# How to overcome py4j error related to picking

Tags: pyspark

Can anyone advise me what I am doing wrong below?

I am getting this error & can't find an answer on Dr Google :(

It seems to be specifically related to my filtering line

```
pickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize object: Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o85.__getnewargs__. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method __getnewargs__([]) does not exist
```

Thanks a lot!

```
def find_session_time(seconds):
    output = sessions.filter((sessions.start_time <= seconds) & (sessions.end_time >= seconds))
    output = output.select('apn')
    return 'x' 
    
myudf = udf(find_session_time, StringType())
usage = usage.withColumn('apn', myudf(usage.seconds))
```

Here is an example of usage:
[image]

and here is an example of sessions:
[image]

The thing I need to achieve is FOR each user, find the corresponding key for their transaction.

Hence the output should be:
[image]

Comment: What is `sessions`?

Comment: its a dataframe - I want to find the corresponiding values between the usage and sessions dataframes

Comment: You can't use it like that in a UDF. That is why you're getting the error. Please remember UDF is a row wise process

Comment: so i can't filter another dataframe within the UDF, using the row wise value I passed in as the filter condition? Because it is still a row-based process

Comment: You cannot access self or other dataframe within a UDF. You don't need a UDF for what you are doing

Comment: May you help me? I have seconds in usage and in sessions I have start and end. So I am looking only for the value where seconds (in usage) is between start and end value in sessions

Comment: Please update your question with a minimum reproducible sample of data and update your question to explain the problem, and expected output.